# Apache Spark 2.1.1 how to set hive.serialization.extend.nesting.levels property to true

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to perform some queries on nested data from my JSON data, but spark complains that my data (8) exceeds the level of nesting supported for LazySimpleSerde (7). I cannot figure out how to set the hive.serialization.extend.nesting.levels property to true.

Spark Log:

> org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException Number of levels of nesting supported for LazySimpleSerde is 7 Unable to work with level 8. Use hive.serialization.extend.nesting.levels serde property for tables using LazySimpleSerde.

Comment: have yo tried to set it via spark? `sparkSession.sql("set hive.serialization.extend.nesting.levels = true")`

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I tried that and it did not work as I am still getting the same error. I wonder you need to set it specifically for tables using LazySimpleSerde?

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 possibilities which you could try in spark:

for a new SparkSession:

```
val sparkSession =
  SparkSession.builder
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("MyApp")
    .config("set hive.serialization.extend.nesting.levels","true")
    .getOrCreate()
```

For existing SparkSession:

```
sparkSession.sql("set hive.serialization.extend.nesting.levels = true")
```

or

```
sparkSession.conf.set("set hive.serialization.extend.nesting.levels","true")
```

But I'm not sure whether this works for this specific property, but I often set e.g. `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode` at runtime using above methods

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem in Spark 2.3.0 when trying to create a table.  I read through the spark code and found the answer.  Add the following to the end of your create table statement

TBLPROPERTIES('hive.serialization.extend.nesting.levels'='true')